# Add exisitng Angular.js app to visual studio solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know how to add an exisiting project (created with [this plugin](https://github.com/jlmonteagudo/generator-angular-crud)) to a Visual Studio solution?
It used bower and npm to install dependecies, so I'm afraid this is not possible.

I know how to create Angular project in Visual Studio from the begging (choosing APS MVC project template).

Comment: Do you mean VS 2013? VS 2015 includes and/or supports many new technologies like npm, node and bower.

Comment: I've never used this plugin, but if you're worried about bower and its dependencies, you can run in windows easily. You must install nodejs and Git for windows, so bower will also work too.

Comment: @Sander_P yes, 2013, we use it in our company.

Comment: @RicardoPontual I know I can install them, but I don't know how to import the whole project to VS, so that I could start the client debugger.

Comment: `File -> open -> website` should work.... or just copying the folder the project is in into a sub-folder of an existing solution? it's not really clear what you are having trouble with here.  `Add -> Empty Project`, copy the files in; or use a plugin to run bower in visual studio....

Comment: I was working in a similar structure from a project I downloaded from Git. I started a new project in VS and copied the files from project I've downloaded in same folder, then I added as existing folder to VS. I don't know any solution to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

1. You first create a web project;
2. go to CMD and the project root folder
3. initialize npm - npm init
4. initialize bower - bower init
5. then install the plugin
6. go to visual studio and add the folders that are in the project into the solution (bower and npm folders)
7. also add bower and npm files to the solution

Notice that this plugin is used via Yeoman, so you've got to use the command yo as show in the plugin website.

When you have all the scaffolding code you need you can add it to the project and use it in any way you want.

Comment: When npm files ale included Visual Studio hangs - I guess file names are too long... But I will try this solution.